# How to adjust an executable to have it stop emitting "allow this program app to make changes" in windows 10

Tags: windows, winapi

We have an ancient win32 product that some customers still want to run in Windows 10, but in some cases several of its components (win32 executables) produce said message when run, while installing and after installing :

"Do you want to allow this app/program to make changes in your PC".

Is there any documentation of what Windows checks to emit the message ?

Comment: Sounds like UAC and application virtualization. But perhaps you need to understand your program. If you don't, what chance do we have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you're seeing is the UAC prompt, and it appears because Windows thinks the program wants admin privileges.

Ancient programs don't have manifests.  Modern versions of Windows guess at whether really old programs require admin privileges.  If the name of the program sounds like it would be an installer (e.g., setupfoo.exe), it will assume the program needs admin.

But many really old programs, even if they're not installers, often want admin privileges because they often try to do things like save files in the program's installation directory or change machine-wide registry values.  If Windows detects a program attempting this and failing because it doesn't have admin privs, it might adjust the program's compatibility options so that next time it runs as an administrator.  To check this, right-click on the executable file, choose Properties, and select the Compatibility tab.  There you'll find a checkbox named "Run this program as an administrator."

To check if your program has a manifest, open the .EXE in Visual Studio (with just the regular open file command), or other resource viewer/editor tool, and look in the resources to see if it has an `RT_MANIFEST` resource.

If there is no manifest and the program is well-behaved, you can add one that sets the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` node to `asInvoker`.

If it has a manifest, look at the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` node in the XML.  If it's there and it says `requiresAdministrator`, then there's probably nothing you can do.  If it already says `asInvoker`, then something else is going wrong.

To provide or replace the manifest you have two options.  You can create an external manifest file and place it in the same folder with the executable (for some versions of Windows, you also have to tell Windows to rely on the external manifest by changing a registry value).

Alternatively, you can use the manifest tool (mt.exe, which comes with Visual Studio) to embed an appropriate manifest in the executable itself (make a backup of the executable first!). In either case, you want to set the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` node to `asInvoker` to avoid the UAC prompt.

Note that, if the program really does need admin privileges, then providing a manifest that says it doesn't will cause the program to fail certain operations.  The program might crash, or it might appear to work but silently fail to do something important (like saving your work).

Also note that manifests control other important things that you may have to get right, like marking whether the application is DPI-aware or what Windows versions it supports.  So, if you try to add a manifest just to add `asInvoker`, you might also have to add some other important values.  MSDN has lots of documentation on manifests and the manifest tool.

Comment: Instead of "no manifest?, assume program needs admin privs" I think you meant assume program needs no privs.

Comment: "*So Windows's heuristic is: no manifest?, assume program needs admin privs*" - that is not true. Only **certain** non-manifested apps are assumed to need privileges. This is managed by UAC's "Installer Detection" heuristics, as only legacy installers should need privileges. Non-installers are NOT granted privileges by default. See [Understanding and Configuring User Account Control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628.aspx) and [UAC Architecture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835540.aspx). Adding a UAC manifest disables Installer Detection.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  It assumes admin if it looks like an installer.  But I think there's also a compatibility shim that can kick if it tried to do something that required admin in the past.  I'll edit to clarify.